# I use \u00AD but the word breaks at another place, why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The variable props.title is "Reichsbahn\u00ADausbesserungs\u00ADwerk Warschauer Straße" but the word breaks like this:
Reichsbahnausbesse-
rungswerk Warschauer Straße

How is this possible?

[image: 1]

```
function Header(props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View style={[styles.header, props.noArrow ? styles.headerNoArrow : null ]}>
            <Text style={[styles.headerText, props.style=="grey" ? styles.textDark : null ]}>{props.title}</Text>
            { !props.noArrow && 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                <Image
                style={{width: 24, height: 22, top: 8, marginRight: 25 }}
                source={require('../../assets/images/arrow-left-yellow.png')}
                /> 
            </TouchableOpacity> 
            } 
        </View>

    )
   
}
export default Header


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginBottom: 20,
        paddingLeft: CSS.margin,
        marginTop: 20,
        minHeight: 70,
    },
    headerText: {
        color: CSS.grey,
        fontFamily: CSS.font1,
        fontSize: CSS.headlineSize,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 10,
        lineHeight: CSS.headlineLH,
        flex: 1,
    },
    headerNoArrow: {
        marginBottom: 38
    },
    textDark: {
        color: '#1A2637'
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Does the containing element have a style that sets [`hyphens`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Soft hyphen in HTML (<wbr> vs. &shy;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226464/soft-hyphen-in-html-wbr-vs-shy)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski `\u00AD` in a JS string should render to the same value as `&shy;` (or `&#173;`) in HTML. The answers to that question don't answer why in this situation, apparently, the browser is auto-hyphenating and not using the inserted breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mistook the HTML entity with CSS code.

Html entities uses `&xxxx;` syntax.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
}

.shy {
  content: '\u00AD';
}
```

```html
<p class="wrap">Reichsbahn&shy;ausbesserungs&shy;werk Warschauer Straße</p>

<p class="wrap">Reichsbahn<span class="shy"></span>ausbesserungs<span class="shy"></span>werk Warschauer Straße</p>
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer applies to the situation of OP, where they have a JS string that they want to soft-hyphenate when it gets rendered? Your answer only applies to HTML strings.

Comment: My problem is happening in react native not in HTML.